# How can I customize my reducers using @ngrx/data?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I am learning to use @ngrx/data, it is true that with that library I advance a lot of code, but I am having problems when it comes to personalizing it. 
I already saw how to add fields to collections

`export const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  User: {
    additionalCollectionState: {
      testing: null
    }
  }
};`

and set the module here:

```
export class UsersModule {
  constructor(private eds: EntityDefinitionService) {
    eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);
  }
}
```

All good up there, but ..., How can I add my own reducers, 
in the documentation I don't see it very clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply follow their docs how to add custom reducers: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-reducer#customizing-entity-reducer-behavior

You can create a custom reducer for an entity type and register it directly with `EntityCollectionReducerRegistry.registerReducer()`.

You can register several custom reducers at the same time by calling `EntityCollectionReducerRegistry.registerReducers(reducerMap)` where the reducerMap is a hash of reducers, keyed by entity-type-name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: https://slides.com/jiali/deck-5/fullscreen#/36

```
ngrx/data extension points
Change built in behaviors
Customized EntityCollectionService
Customized EntityAction/Dispatcher
Add property to EntityCollection
Customized DataService
Customized merge strategy
Customized http url generator
Customized plural names
Customized persistentResultHandler
Use normal ngrx
Dispatch own action
Add own reducer/effects
```