# how to EXTEND Custom Entity Collection Reducers in @ngrx/data

Tags: angular, ngrx-entity, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

After reading and trying everything so far to update my additionalCollectionStates to my EntityCollection (based on the few infos from the docs, [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543031/overwriting-handlesuccess-of-ngrx-defaultpersistenceresulthandler?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this other SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073752/ngrx-data-how-can-i-extend-a-collection-reducer-replace-handling-of-the-res), [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296660/how-can-i-customize-my-reducers-using-ngrx-data) and an [issue from the github repository](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2434)) I find myself stuck with what should be a fairly common task to do and was no problem at all before using ngrx: sorting of a stored collection of entities with ngrx. Searching for solutions takes me back to the same 10 links I have already seen 5 times and most examples are either too basic or outdated or don't use ngrx/data at all or similar questions don't have answers at all.

**Environment**: Angular 9.1.7, ngrx 9.1.2, macOS 10.14.6

**Goal**

Add and update own `additionalCollectionState` to my EntityCollection as described [in the docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#additionalcollectionstate) for sorting and pagination. I **do not** get the *sortQuery* Properties (sortField, sortDirection) from the server but rather set it in my GUI and sort the collection based on them. I know there exists the `sortComparer` setting on EntityMetadataMap but it's not flexible enough for my means, I want to dynamically sort the collections in different MatTables across the app. This additional property should be updated, whenever the sort order / field in a MatTable changes.

**What I have achieved so far:**

The ngrx/data way of additionalCollectionState as desribed above *works*, my collection is *initialized* with the data I provided in the EntityMetadataMap. Updating the custom collection properties however does not work in the way it is understood by me from the docs. Since I don't get the *sortQuery* property from the server, the ResultsHandler is not called.

I approached this problem in two ways: a) using ngrx & ngrx/entity Methods and b) the ngrx/data way by trying to extend a custom [EntityCollectionReducer](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-reducer#register-custom-reducers)

a) I was successful in creating a custom Action and custom Reducer and updating a *state property* but not the previously defined *collection property*. My action is basically:

```
export const selectResourceSortQuery = createAction('[Resource] Get Last Sort Query', props<{ sortQuery: any }>());
```

It is called from a service with:

```
    this.store.dispatch(selectResourceSortQuery({ sortQuery }));
```

and handled in the reducer:

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as ResourceActions from './resource.actions';
import { Resource } from 'src/app/sdk';

export interface State extends EntityState<Resource> {
    // additional state property
    sortQuery: any | null;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Resource> = createEntityAdapter<Resource>();

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    // additional entity state properties
    sortQuery: {
        sortDirection: 'asc',
        sortField: 'product'
    },
});

export const resourceReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ResourceActions.selectResourceSortQuery, (state, { sortQuery }) => {
        console.log(`REDUCER called`);
        return { ...state, sortQuery };
    }),
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
    return resourceReducer(state, action);
}
```

The reducers are exported in reducers/index.ts:

```
import {
  ActionReducer,
  ActionReducerMap,
  createFeatureSelector,
  createSelector,
  MetaReducer
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import * as fromResourceReducers from 'src/app/store/entities/resource/resource.reducer';


export interface State {

}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  resourceSort: fromResourceReducers.reducer
};


export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [] : [];
```

In app.module this is setup as:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
  metaReducers: [
    ngrxEntityRelationshipReducer //ignore this
  ],
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true
  }
}),
```

This creates a *resourceSort* Collection with the *sortQuery* property as visible from this screenshot: [image] and updates it also according to the changed sortQuery property. However, I would prefer using the already initialized sortQuery property in the Resource entityCache collection (yeah, I also tried adding it to the *entityCache* feature with    `StoreModule.forFeature('entityCache', reducers)` ignore that):

[image]

b) Therefore, another approach was to use the EntityCollectionReducerRegistry in app.module:

```
import { resourceReducer } from './store/entities/resource/resource.reducer';

// does not work: resourceReducer is of type ActionReducer<State, Action> and the same as posted above (with the added handling of the sortQuery property), and apparently what this function expects
entityCollectionReducerRegistry.registerReducer('Resources', resourceReducer);

// this does work, but just creates the basic default entity collection reducer without my custom sortQuery handling
entityCollectionReducerRegistry.registerReducer('Resources', entityCollectionReducerFactory.create('resources'))
```

From the docs:

> The Entity Reducer is the master reducer for all entity collections in the stored entity cache. The library doesn't have a named entity reducer type. Rather it relies on the EntityCacheReducerFactory.create() method to produce that reducer, which is an NgRx ActionReducer<EntityCache, EntityAction>.

I have a feeling, with the b) approach I might be on the right track, however I'm stuck with the lack of documentation and examples how to handle this problem - is there anybody able to help me?

If more details are needed I am happy to provide them, and if something is unclear since English is not my native language I'm happy to clarify, and if necessary try to provide a simplified stackblitz example. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've approached this the same way I did initially: trying to register a custom reducer to handle the additionalCollectionState properties. After spending some time deciphering the documentation, I was finally able to update a collection property. Here's what the docs say and how I did it:

> The NgRx Data library generates selectors for these properties, but
> has no way to update them. You'll have to create or extend the
> existing reducers to do that yourself.
> ([additionalCollectionState](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#additionalcollectionstate))

After this it goes on with the backend example, but I don't need that; yet, I used the information from step 2 onwards to extend (to be read hack) the EntityCollectionReducerMethods to intercept my property:

**extended-entity-collection-reducer-methods.ts**

```
export class ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethods<T> extends EntityCollectionReducerMethods<T> {
    constructor(
        public entityName: string,
        public definition: EntityDefinition<T>) {
        super(entityName, definition);
    }

    protected updateOne(collection: EntityCollection<T>, action: EntityAction<Update<T>>): EntityCollection<T> {
    const superMethod = {...super.updateOne(collection, action)};

    if (action.payload.entityName === 'Project' &&
        (action.payload.data.changes as any).id === 0) {
        (superMethod as any).lastProjectId = (action.payload.data.changes as any).lastProjectId;
    }

    return superMethod;
}
```

This then needs to be instantiated by the Factory:

**extended-entity-collection-reducer-methods-factory.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory {
    constructor(
        private entityDefinitionService: EntityDefinitionService
    ) {
    }

    create<T>(entityName: string): EntityCollectionReducerMethodMap<T> {
        const definition = this.entityDefinitionService.getDefinition<T>(entityName);
        const methodsClass = new ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethods(entityName, definition);
        return methodsClass.methods;
    }
}
```

The ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory needs to replace the original one.

**app-module.ts**

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
            useClass: ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory
        }
    ]
```

Now you have a sneaky way of doing this in your component:

```
this.someService.updateOneInCache({id: 0, lastProjectId: projectId} as any);
```

someService needs to extend the marvelous EntityCollectionServiceBase class:

**some-service.ts**

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SomeService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<SomeEntity> {
    constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
        super('SomeEntity', serviceElementsFactory);
    }
}
```

The updateOne method in ExtendedEntityCollectionReducerMethods will pick the property up through the action's payload and you can set it there before you return the result of the superMethod.

I find this kind of cringy, but it works. I found no other way to update a collection's additional properties after trying in vain to go about using the EntityCacheReducerFactory and its weird fellows.

I've set the id to 0 for the update method because otherwise it will complain the id is missing. Since I don't have any entity with an id of 0, it should work without any unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks man, you're doing the Lords work! After weeks, even months of not coming to a solution this just works - and until there is a better/official method or at least documentation or best practice I'm going to use this approach

Comment: @hreimer Glad I could be of help. All glory is due to the Lord and Saviour Jesus Christ. I would not have been a programmer if it was not for him.

Comment: @RepentAndBelieveTheGospel hi man. Thanks for the great post... will this work if I have multiple injections to do in the module? How would I approach that?

Comment: @Morfinismo What do you mean by multiple injections? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RepentAndBelieveTheGospel I meant this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796773/ngrx-data-providing-multiple-entitycollectionreducermethodsfactory-classes-to?noredirect=1#comment119834478_67796773

Comment: @Morfinismo Let's continue the discussion there.