# NGRX Data - Providing multiple EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory classes to Module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-ngrx-data

Following the documentation for [additional collection state](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#additionalcollectionstate), I have been able to make it work with only one entity collection. In the module I am building I am using three entity collections so far. I'm not sure how the injection in the module should be done but this is what I am doing:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedPharmaCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,

    },
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedClnicalCollectionReducerMethodsFactory
    },
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedUsersCollectionReducerMethodsFactory
    }
  ]
```

The above approach is not working. What I've noticed is that the last provider is overring the top two. For example, in the above example, the injected service that works is the `ExtendedUsersCollectionReducerMethodsFactory`. If I change the order like this:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedClnicalCollectionReducerMethodsFactory
    },
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedUsersCollectionReducerMethodsFactory
    },
    {
      provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
      useClass: ExtendedPharmaCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,

    }
  ]
```

Then the one that works is the `ExtendedPharmaCollectionReducerMethodsFactory`. My question is the following....

How can I provide different `EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory` for different entity collections?

Comment: Just look at what you’re telling the computer to do, replace 1 class with 3. That cannot possibly work. Provide one factory class and with that class condition on the `entityName`

Comment: Can you provide the contents of these factory classes?